# Laravel5 - Carbon hardcode translating

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, translation

Stackers!
I'm pretty new to L5 yet I know it a bit already. I've recently come across a problem I can't resolve. Maybe it's just me being incredibly stupid but here's the question-
I started using Carbon, "diffForHumans" to be exact. I get proper result but I can't figure out how to change the output like "9 hours ago" to my native language. I found out on some forums that this output depends on your OS's language, so if this is true I'd like to hard-code the translations (if it's possible) because I'm using English version of OS but I want the output to be in my native no matter what. I tried in "Carbon\Carbon.php" file but haven't found anything useful. 
Am I really that blind? 
Thanks in advance! :)
Talky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a localized package or localized extension of Carbon like 
***localized-carbon***

https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon

<del>However, support for L5 is not yet ready, as can be seen in the [list of issues](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon/issues/28)</del>.

Now L5 is supported.